# SSL авторизация на сайте по сертификату в связке с логином и паролем

Tags: ssl, java

Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Необходима авторизация на сайте https://test.local, для авторизации используется сертификат cert.pfx и связка логин:пароль. 
cert.pfx - я экспортировал из браузера firefox, что бы действительно убедиться что сертификат верный я его импортировал(в веб браузер) на другие машины. авторизация проходила успешно.

Из полученного сертифката я создал keystore.jks

```
openssl pkcs12 -in custom_cert.p12 -out custom_cert.pem -nodes -nokeys
openssl pkcs12 -in custom_cert.p12 -out custom_key.pem -nodes -nocerts

openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in custom_key.pem -inform PEM -out custom_key.der -outform DER
openssl x509 -in custom_cert.pem -inform PEM -out custom_cert.der -outform DER
```

Вот так вот выглядит мое подключение

```
String URL = "test.local";

 try {

            KeyStore kS = KeyStore.getInstance( KeyStore.getDefaultType() );
            FileInputStream fIS = new FileInputStream("keystore.jks"); 
            kS.load(fIS, "123456".toCharArray());

            KeyManagerFactory kMF = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kMF.init(kS, "123456".toCharArray());
            KeyManager[] kMs = kMF.getKeyManagers();

            TrustManagerFactory tMF = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            tMF.init(kS);
            TrustManager[] tM = tMF.getTrustManagers();


            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(kMs, tM, new SecureRandom());
            SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext);
            javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            SSLSocket sslClientSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(URL,443);
            sslClientSocket.startHandshake();


            HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost(URL, 443, "https");
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);



            CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credsProvider.setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(),443),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("Fedya.Ivakin", "191919"));

            HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                    .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                    .setSslcontext(sslContext)
                    .build();

            AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();           
            BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
            authCache.put(targetHost, basicAuth);

            HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
            context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("/");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(targetHost, httpget, context);
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
```

В результате получаю HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden.

Хотя ошибок ни каких нет, куда копать? подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Кучу сайтов перерыл. Встречал такие утверждения, что `pkcs12` сертификаты `java` не понимает и надо их конвертировать и кучу еще чего. Но вот так у меня проходит авторизация по сертификату + логин пароль.

```
String URL = "https://test.local:443";

URL url = new URL(URL);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setSSLSocketFactory(getFactory1(new File("key/User.pfx"), "123456"));

Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
con.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.connect();
```

`domain` необходимо указывать именно через два слеша, плюс не нужно указывать зону(ru и тп). Например логин и пароль у нас такой `Ivan.Petrov@domain.ru` - это логин, `123456` - это пароль

```
class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("domain\\Ivan.Petrov", "123456".toCharArray());
    }
 }
```

==

```
private SSLSocketFactory getFactory1(File pKeyFile, String pKeyPassword) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException {

    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

    InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(pKeyFile);
    keyStore.load(keyInput, pKeyPassword.toCharArray());
    keyInput.close();


    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, pKeyPassword.toCharArray());


    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
                    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }

                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }


                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }

            }
    };


    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());


    return context.getSocketFactory();
}
```

Ничего ни пришлось конвертировать и тп. Необходимо экспортировать сертификат пользователя из браузера и закинуть его в приложение.

Comment: Ничего ни пришлось конвертировать и тп. Необходимо экспортировать сертификат пользователя из браузера и закинуть его в приложение.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте, попробуйте как описано [здесь](http://samonesoznanie.blogspot.com/2012/01/tomcat-jar-ssl-https.html)