# Java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE

Tags: httpsurlconnection, ssl, android, java, httpclient

Добрый день.

Есть сервис к которому необходимо слать запросы, сервис просит NTLM авторизации и подписания всех запросов сертифкатом(PKCS12)

Есть код который работает в PC клиенте([HttpsURLConnection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/269321/java-ssl-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC)), но на андроиде код не пошел, точнее подключения создавалось отлично, но вот авторизация(NTML) не проходила

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("domain\\User.Name",  "password".toCharArray());                
            }
        } );
```

метод getPasswordAuthentication(), даже не вызывался. Было такое мнение, что в андроиде, есть аутентификатор у которого приоритет выше и он блокирует Authenticator.setDefault, но ни найти его и тем более выключить я не смог.

Подумав, я решил взять апачесвкую библиотеку httpclient-4.3.1
Набросав код который работает на локальной машине

```
package com.example.HttpsMy;

import android.os.Environment;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;


import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class HttpsClietn {
    HttpsClietn() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {

        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new NTCredentials("Grigoriy.Polyakov","password", "", "domain.kz"));

        HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        context.setCredentialsProvider(credsProvider);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://serveer.domain.kz");


       HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
               .setSSLSocketFactory(getFactory())
               .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
               .setSslcontext(getContext())
               .build();

        System.out.println(client.execute(httpget,context).getStatusLine());

    }

    SSLContext getContext() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, IOException, KeyManagementException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        //new File("key/keystore.p12"), "1234"
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

        InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/kvv/keystore.p12"));
        keyStore.load(keyInput, "1234".toCharArray());
        keyInput.close();

        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "1234".toCharArray());

        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
        };

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

        return context;
    }

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory getFactory() throws CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException, IOException {
        return new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(getContext());
    }
}
```

но при запуске(вызываю в самом первом активити в методе onCreate )

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    new HttpsClietn();
    }
}).run();
```

получаю ошибку

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE

буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836012/how-to-override-android-api-class-with-a-class-available-in-added-jar

Answer (score 2):

Вместо библиотеки которую вы прописываете в classpath вашего проекта используется встроенная в Android устаревшая версия apache http, в которой этого поля действительно нет.

Проблема существует уже давно ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915141/how-to-override-or-apache-http-in-android-platform),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836012/how-to-override-android-api-class-with-a-class-available-in-added-jar)).

**Решения**:
 - используйте [jarjar](https://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) и перепакуйте библиотеку с использованием другого пэкэджа.
 - воспользуйтесь готовым перепакованным решением - [httpclientandroidlib](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/)
 - если используете Maven возьмите [shade](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html).

Comment: спасибо, да так и поступил, перепаковал либу и все стало как часы работать.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что у вас не хватает библиотеки httpCore. См. информацию на странице проекта [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/)