# OkHttpClient3 авторизация через сертификат

Tags: java, ssl, okhttp

Пишу сервер для приема платежей и для взаимодействия с платежной системой требуется авторизация через сертификат.
Есть `*.pem` и `*.p12` файлы, в браузере я добавил файл `*.p12` для проверки того что система его принимает.
Http-запросы отправляю через OkHttp3, поискал пару примеров как можно настроить, но не нашел примера авторизации через сертификат.

Пробовал [этот вариант](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java) и [этот](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/cd872fd83824512c128dcd80c04d445c8a2fc8eb/okhttp-tests/src/test/java/okhttp3/internal/tls/ClientAuthTest.java), но получаю ошибку:

```
PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target`
```

---

#### UPDATE #1

Есть ПС (платежная система) moneta, при запросе можно передать логин/пароль или подписать запрос сертификатом который создается в личном кабинете.
Для теста я установил этот сертификат в свой браузер и зашел по ссылке которая возвращает чек об оплате, и это сработало.
Теперь мне нужно что бы мой сервер которой взаимодействует с ПС мог свои запросы подписать этим сертификатом, в сервере в качестве http-клиента используется OkHttp3.

---

#### РЕШЕНИЕ

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/269321/ssl-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC) в последнем ответе пример оказался рабочим.

Comment: В браузере вы сохранили клиентский сертификат, поидее вам надо ещё добавить в jks сертификат на стороне сервера. То есть `keytool -import -alias example -keystore  ПУТЬ_К_JRE/security/cacerts -file mycert.der`

Comment: @Chubatiy обновил вопрос